# Standard Scaler inverse_transform working for any shape?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am scaling only one column of a dataframe `df1['a']`

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]], columns=['a', 'b','c'])
scaler1 = StandardScaler()
scaled1 = scaler1.fit_transform(df1[['a']])
```

I have another dataframe df2 that has two rows of the scaled values:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(scaled1, columns=['a'])
df2['b'] = pd.DataFrame(scaled1, columns=['b'])
```

Strangely the inverse_transform work with df2

```
scaler1.inverse_transform(df2)
```

But this should not happen since scaler 1 was fitted with 1D data. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your wording is a bit unclear. Please provide a [mre]. (See [ask].)

Answer (score 1):

If read the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95119c13a/sklearn/preprocessing/_data.py#L902), to perform the inverse transform, it uses [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#:%7E:text=The%20term%20broadcasting%20describes%20how,that%20they%20have%20compatible%20shapes.) to multiply the array by the standard deviation and add the mean. so the special case is when your mean and standard deviation has length 1.

Using your example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]], columns=['a', 'b','c'])
scaler1 = StandardScaler()
scaled1 = scaler1.fit_transform(df1[['a']])
```

So these will work:

```
np.random.seed(111)
test = np.random.uniform(0,10,(3,3))

scaler1.inverse_transform(test)

array([[7.12170176, 2.69069754, 5.36059019],
       [8.69262473, 3.95325304, 2.49162957],
       [1.22478325, 5.20224492, 3.38682141]])
```

Because this works:

```
test * scaler1.scale_ + scaler1.mean_
Out[89]: 
array([[7.12170176, 2.69069754, 5.36059019],
       [8.69262473, 3.95325304, 2.49162957],
       [1.22478325, 5.20224492, 3.38682141]])
```

You can try it when input is an array with 2 or more columns, the above will fail.